# iTunes can no longer find music files after changing IP address of NAS

Tags: itunes, network, nas

I have a problem with finding my music again in iTunes after the IP address was changed of my NAS where all my music resides.

After switching internet providers, I changed the layout of my home network. Formerly my NAS could be reached on IP 192.168.0.12, but the new modem demands another IP range, so my NAS is now at 192.168.1.200.

I connect to my NAS (QNAP TS-410) through NFS to a folder called QMultimedia. I mapped the folder to Finder so I have easy access to it and iTunes uses that folder. Next to NFS, I use the same mapping via a Samba share and an AFP share through Bonjour.

After I changed the network location everything is working fine (XBMC, Finder, Time-Machine), except that iTunes cannot find any of my music anymore. If I open a track in iTunes, it will hang for a while (showing the eternal flame for a minute) and then display a message that is could not find the track because it cannot find the path (192.168.0.12, the old location) and if I want to search for it. I can, but I can only do that for a single track and with a few hundred tracks of music, it is an impossible job to remap my music this way.

*Did someone experienced this before and how did you solve it? Is there a way to get it easily working again without reorganizing and relabeling all my music in iTunes again? Any suggestions are welcome!*

I am experienced with PCs and networking, but a little new with OSX, the Terminal and Bash. I am running iTunes 10.6.3 on a mid-2010 MBP on Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 1):

As I can't comment on post so it comes as an answer:

Are your iTunes library accessing the NAS as a shared library or as imported files?

If it's imported files the "file location" stored in your iTunes library still contain the old IP. Changing all of these will take forever and I do not know if there is any application or plugin that can batch-change them. Deleting all files and importing them again might be the easiest solution to your problem.

You can see the songs location in the `Get info -> Summary -> "Where:"`

Comment: As imported files and as you mentioned: It takes indeed forever to change it. I tried to change the location of some numbers in the .xml but that did not work out very well. Well, time for a fresh library then.

Comment: It will indeed go faster and you don't have to take any action while importing it. It's just pain to download new artwork and generate continuous play. Not to mention generating a new Genius if your library is big.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have rebooted the NAS since this change occurred.
2. Access the QNAP admin screen using your web browser.
   a. login with the admin account
   b. navigate to Applications->iTunes Server
   c. verify Enable iTunes server is checked
   d. set a new password for the iTunes server if you do not remember it
   e. click apply
   f. access the iTunes server using the link right above the password box, it should be http://192.168.1.200:3689 in your case
   g. check for any errors
   h. restart iTunes
   i. in the top left of iTunes, there is an icon with a Music note, if your iTunes server is running on your network, you should be able to select this drop down and change the server your iTunes client is accessing