# itunes 12 renaming song database

Tags: itunes, nas

I have a Nas with my iTunes library, `/Volumes/music` is my `itunes media`folder.
I created one playlist and today I have something strange for some songs

```
+------------+-----------------+------------------+ 
|name        | artist          |album             | 
+-------------------------------------------------+ 
|a movie name|                 |an album name     | 
|from Video* |                 |from music        | 
+------------+-----------------+------------------+
```

- video is a volume on my nas…

 + i (information) for this song >
name : Dragon II (2013),
artist : empty,
album : Mozart greatest hit

Another mistake (red line is for /.../.../....nfo) :
[image: information]

---

### In finder all is OK ("18 messe pour...") !

[image: finder]

how to fix this ?

Comment: The path to location is wrong… /volumes/video/… so iTunes can't play/find - I never put this file in this volume…

Comment: Does the solution in http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60330/itunes-can-not-find-music-anymore-after-changing-ip-address-of-nas?rq=1 help?

Comment: No… I can delete and import file but I had the same problem few days after.

Comment: Might be the NAS interacting with the way iTunes manages its library. Can you add a screenshot showing the right-most part of the preferences dialog (where "iTunes Media" location is defined)? Also, is `/Volumes/video` a valid path/mount point at all? And if yes, is it pointing to the same NAS?

Comment: This is on the same nas and it's pointing to an existing file (dot nfo). I don't understand how itunes can go to this folder.

Comment: Where does "iTunes Media" in iTunes preferences point to?

Comment: It was `/Volumes/music`, now it's `/Volumes/music/Music`…

Comment: ITunes 12 is a bad version… or it's my computer. Song information are changing, now I have bad meta "album artist" for a song is from another song.